# Need to know keyboard shortcut to navigate without using mouse in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, keyboard, shortcut

I would hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and Click on the name of the class in my build path to navigate to that Class.

Please help me in finding the keyboard shortcut without using the mouse click.

Answer (score 1):

Keyboard shortcut to navigate into classes (or variable declarations) is <kbd>F3</kbd>.

See [this article](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseShortcuts/article.html) for more useful shortcuts (or just google for another page about eclipse shortcuts)